# Akita as my hunting buddy

Tags: hunting, dogs

I thought about trying unconventional breeds for hunting. I stumbled across the "[Akita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akita_%28dog%29)", which was initially cultured to hunt. However, it seems that it's pretty much a common house/pet dog nowadays (nothing wrong with this of course).

How does an Akita do as a hunting buddy?

The Japanese [Akita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akita_%28dog%29#Working_life):

> Working life
>
> Predecessors of the modern Akita were used for hunting bear, wild boar
>   and deer in Japan as late as 1957.[67] They would be used to flush out
>   the bear and keep it at bay until the hunter could come and kill it.
>   Today, the breed is used primarily as a companion dog. However, the
>   breed is currently also known to be used as therapy dogs,[68] and
>   compete in all dog competitions including: conformation showing,
>   obedience trials, canine good citizen program, tracking trials and
>   agility competition,[69] as well as weight pulling, hunting and
>   schutzhund (i.e., personal protection dogs).[70]

Comment: This'll depend on how you bring it up - how you train it, and each individual dogs instincts ( and a little bit to do with how smart they are) I've a Shetland Sheepdog, but he's a loveable idiot and there's no way he'd be any good realistically at herding sheep, but that's not true of all Shelties. If you're going to put in the time and like the Akita then go for it... It's sort of opinion based really. You can't expect the dog to just get it, it'll have to go Hunt training. My sisters doing the same for her Sprocker gun dog.

Comment: @OddDeer With this breed i believe you would be ok but I would put a big emphasis on the success being attributed to training.

Comment: As a hunting buddy? Long ago, I took my brother's untrained Akita pheasant hunting once. He was very attentive and energetic but had no clue what we were doing. He was fun to roam the fields with (good buddy) but he wasn't hunting. Years later, the same brother bought an Akita mix as a house pet. It quickly cleaned out all of the gophers on his property. So I guess it enjoyed hunting.